# where did i go wrong? (I'm a beginner), and how do I make it right?

Tags: python

```
>>> def f(x):
... return x**2
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    return x**2
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: you need to indent the return statement (add 4 spaces)

Answer (score -1):

Here you are:

```
>>> def f(x):
...     return x**2 
... 
>>> f(2) 
4
```

> Python Indentation
>
> Indentation refers to the spaces at the beginning of a code line.
>
> Where in other programming languages the indentation in code is for
> readability only, the indentation in Python is very important.
>
> Python uses indentation to indicate a block of code.

For more information regarding indentation please [check this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_indentation.asp).